# Excluding a function from gprof results

Tags: c, linux, gprof

I want to exclude some functions from the output generated by gprof. In other words, I do not want them to be included when calculating percentage time spent by each function during execution. I read at one place **-E** option can be used.

However I'm using **gprof -E function_to_be_exluded my_program_name**, but nothing happens. The manual says it is depreciated and you should use **symspecs** instead. However, I have wasted half an hour trying to figure out how to achieve it with **symspecs**, but no luck. Anyone can kindly help me in this.

Comment: What language are you profiling? C? C++? Something else? Name mangling or namespaces might be affecting it.

Comment: No name mangling because I'm using pure C

Comment: Oh God! I have gone so frustrated that now I'm writing my own program to filter out those functions from a flat profile! sucks man!

Comment: Do you want [`attribute((no_instrument_function))`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bno_005finstrument_005ffunction_007d-function-attribute-2454) by any chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly, gprof -e -E are deprecated and superseded by usage of newer relevant options that have argument - symspecs. So try using:

```
gprof --no-time=symspec 

The -n option causes "gprof", in its call graph analysis, not to propagate times for
symbols matching symspec.

e.g.

gprof --no-time=name_of_function_you_dont_want_to_profile.
```

Use this along with your other gprof options (-E -e definitely ruled out)

Comment: How to do it for multiple functions?

Comment: @MetallicPriest - Not tried myself but to use this for multiple functions give the option --no-time multiple times with different function names. Did u try this already?

Answer (score 4):

According to the man:

- for display flat profile and exclude function from it you need use `-P` option:

  ```
  gprof main gmon.out -Pfunction_name
  ```
- for display call graph and exclude function from it you need use `-Q` option:

  ```
  gprof main gmon.out -Qfunction_name
  ```

This options can be repeated and used in the same time:

```
gprof main gmon.out -Pfunction_name -Qfunction_name -Qother_function_name
```

If you need exclude function from one report but not exclude any function from other you need use `-p` or `-q` options.

**Example:**

Create program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func_a () {printf ("%s ",__FUNCTION__);}
void func_b () {printf ("%s ",__FUNCTION__);}
void func_c () {printf ("%s ",__FUNCTION__);}

int main ()
{
    func_a ();
    func_b ();
    func_c ();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile it:
`gcc main.c -pg -o main`

And launch:

```
$ ./main
func_a func_b func_c
```

Generate profile reports:

- If you need print only flat profile you need call:

  ```
  $ gprof main gmon.out -b -p  
    %   cumulative   self              self     total             
   time   seconds   seconds    calls  Ts/call  Ts/call  name      
    0.00      0.00     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  func_a  
    0.00      0.00     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  func_b  
    0.00      0.00     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  func_c
  ```
- If you need print flat profile excluding functions `func_a` and `func_c` and full call graph you need call:

  ```
  $ gprof main gmon.out -b -Pfunc_a -Pfunc_c -q
    %   cumulative   self              self     total           
   time   seconds   seconds    calls  Ts/call  Ts/call  name    
    0.00      0.00     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  func_b

  index % time    self  children    called     name
                  0.00    0.00       1/1           main [9]
  [1]      0.0    0.00    0.00       1         func_a [1]
  -----------------------------------------------
                  0.00    0.00       1/1           main [9]
  [2]      0.0    0.00    0.00       1         func_b [2]
  -----------------------------------------------
                  0.00    0.00       1/1           main [9]
  [3]      0.0    0.00    0.00       1         func_c [3]
  -----------------------------------------------
  ```
- If you need print flat profile excluding functions `func_a` and `func_c` and call graph excluding `func_b` you need call:

  ```
  $ gprof main gmon.out -b -Pfunc_a -Pfunc_c -Qfunc_b
    %   cumulative   self              self     total           
   time   seconds   seconds    calls  Ts/call  Ts/call  name    
    0.00      0.00     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  func_b

  index % time    self  children    called     name
                  0.00    0.00       1/1           main [9]
  [1]      0.0    0.00    0.00       1         func_a [1]
  -----------------------------------------------
                  0.00    0.00       1/1           main [9]  
  [3]      0.0    0.00    0.00       1         func_c [3]
  -----------------------------------------------
  ```

Comment: How to exclude a c++ function？I tried "-P" with  function name of namespace format, eg. util::test_func failed. I also tried symbol name after compile of c++ name rules, failed.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I've misunderstood what you're asking...

gprof  a.out --no-time=function_name

works for me.